# Flutter + Google Maps: How to animate the camera to target location

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3

i was wondering if you could give me an example on "animating" the camera of a map to a target location based on latitude and longitude.

Sorry I'm just very new to flutter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) page. It has exactly the same example you are looking for.

Basically, you can control the camera with the GoogleMapController object after initializing it with the onMapCreated callback of the GoogleMap widget.

```
Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
  final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
  controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
 }
```

Comment: is there a way to control the speed of the camera animation?